# iOS Facebook SDK: which login system is better?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I am developing a iOS application which allows users to login by using their Facebook account.

I managed to implement the login procedure thanks to official tutorial I found here https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk. I found here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/authenticate/ another tutorial which looks pretty different since in the first tutorial the user signs in through Safari, instead in the second tutorial the native Facebook App is used.

Among these two systems, which one is better? Perhaps by using Safari I could avoid any issue concerning back compatibility with older versions of iOS?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the official Facebook SDK, here's what happens:

- If a user **does have** the Facebook app installed, they'll be taken to it to authenticate and login to your app.
- If the user **does not have** the Facebook app installed, they'll be taken to Safari to authenticate and login to your app.

Either way, the login process is the same. After they authenticate, they're returned to your app using a specific URL scheme so that you can continue with what you're doing.

Finally, if you're targeting iOS 6 only, you can take advantage of the single sign on features built into iOS. Check the docs for more information on that.

Comment: Thanks! If I've understood well: the first tutorial I linked shows how to log in WITHOUT SSO, instead the second one shows how to use SSO. Right?

Comment: @pAkY88 There is no tutorial at the first link you posted. When you use the official Facebook SDK, it automatically chooses the best method for authenticating the user based on various different scenarios. You don't need to worry about anything other than the procedure spelled out here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login-with-facebook-using-ios-sdk/

Comment: in the first link there an example which shows how to implement a login flow. Here is the exact link from which I got "inspired" for my application: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/tree/master/samples/SessionLoginSample/SessionLoginSample
What do you think about that? Thanks!

Comment: @pAkY88 that example is using the Facebook SDK, so it will take advantage of SSO if available.